# If $ax+by+cz = 0$, show that $span(x,y)=span(y,z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**If we have $ax+by+cz = 0$ show that $span(x,y)=span(y,z)$**

My steps:

$$x = -\frac{b}{a}y-\frac{c}{a}z\Rightarrow x\ \in\ span(y,z)$$

$$z=-\frac{a}{c}x-\frac{b}{c}y\Rightarrow z \in\ span(x,y)$$

But we still have not proved that $span(x,y)=span(y,z)$ and I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here

Comment: What's to stop you from doing the same thing but for $y$?

Comment: @Integrand because that'll only get me $y \epsilon span(x,z)$

Comment: Right, but if $y\in\text{span}(x,z)$, then what can you say about $\text{span}(x,y)$?

Comment: @Integrand wait would it be right to say since y spans x & z then span(y,z)=span(x,y)? i feel like it's still missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $abc\neq 0$.

As you pointed out, $x\in \text{span}(y,z)$, $z\in \text{span}(x,y)$, and $y\in \text{span}(x,z)$. This means
$$
\text{span}(y,z)\subseteq \text{span}(y,\text{span}(x,y))=\text{span}(x,y)
$$and likewise
$$
\text{span}(x,y)\subseteq \text{span}(y,\text{span}(y,z))=\text{span}(y,z)
$$Another way: the equation is a $2$-dimensional plane, so it should be spanned by any combination of two of the basis vectors.